# how to display Mesh-Like structure with java swing?

Tags: java, swing, structure, mesh, display

I have a list of words with the words having "connections/links" between them

e.g :

- "Philanthropy" is linked to "good work" "welfare" "nice" "help"...
- "help" is linked to "kindness" "love" "cooperation"...
- "love" is linked to "deep feeling" "affection"...

the links may vary with each word having a varying number of links to other words...
 I want to display them in a mesh-like structure with each word encapsulated in a circle with links ("lines") linking them...
How can I accomplish that ? is there any library? or shall I do it manually... and if so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I think you need to draw. Start with a single circle - if you done that, start drawing two circles and try to connect them.

Comment: @louis12356 I thought so but there's toooo much data and i wanna display them all so the screen won't contain, I need to add some scrolling option but how?

Comment: If your content is bigger than your actual browser window, the scroll bars will appear automatically. If not, just set the HTML width/height with CSS to a new standard.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your chosen approach, e.g. [tag:prefuse].